# How to compile from sources Breeze for GTK theme on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, kde, gtk, theme

So, I can't install 'Breeze for GTK' theme on Debian 9. I've downloaded the files from [official git page](https://phabricator.kde.org/source/breeze-gtk/) and when I move the files on ./themes folder system no read them.

And when execute `./build_theme.sh`, the next message appear:

```
/home/pc_home/.config/kdeglobals not found, using defaults
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "render_assets.py", line 717, in <module>
    _colors = ReadKdeGlobals(args.basecolorscheme).read_globals(args.colorscheme)
  File "render_assets.py", line 23, in __init__
    self._colors = self.read_globals(base_file_name)
  File "render_assets.py", line 26, in read_globals
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as _kde:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/color-schemes/Breeze.colors'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Procedure:

- Clone repository:

```bash
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/breeze-gtk
```

- Install required pacakges:

```bash
sudo apt install \
libgtk-3-dev \
gtk2-engines-pixbuf \
sassc \
python3 \
python3-pip
```

- Install cairo python module:

```bash
pip3 install pycairo
```

- Download required color schemes:

```bash
Ver=5.15.5
wget https://download.kde.org/stable/plasma/$Ver/breeze-$Ver.tar.xz
tar -xf breeze-$Ver.tar.xz breeze-$Ver/colors
mv breeze-$Ver/colors colors
```

- Run build script:

```
cd breeze-gtk/src
sh ./build_theme.sh -r ~/colors
```

Run `sh ./build_theme.sh --help` for usage details.

Comment: Thanks for everything @Biswapriyo. By the way, where is all that info?, because on the README file isn't.

Comment: @p_ks I made that with trial and error. I run the script and it says something is missing so I install it and repeat the process.